# Ios-cordova application freezes

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Why cordova application freezes if I click home button on splash screen and than go back?

Page rendered, but there is no reaction for any script, even I make onclick listener for body (

```
<body onclick="alert('hello');">
```

) there is no reaction and debug in safari doesn't work too.

Comment: Please add some more details and code so we can check if where and why the script is not working also you cannot able to use `onclick` event into body tag

Comment: body onclick works if application load success. All click listeners don't work, but setInterval, setTimeout, etc work well.

Comment: Are you using single page application or multi page ? because in single page application the page loads only one time and you cannot re-generate the same document load or device ready event into app.